# semaphore_wait() suddenly aborts

Tags: objective-c, xcode, multithreading, semaphore

I have an app with a thread created as

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

});
```

I suspend all other threads and resume execution of this thread.
And while this thread spinning in a semaphore_wait() function, pausing the application or adding some symbolic breakpoint immediately causes it to exit from this semaphore_wait() although it must not.
I don't know the reason. Could it be XCode(4.5) causing this behaviour?

Comment: The code you show does *not* create a thread. It simply puts a reference to a block on a queue. Internally to GCD, worker threads get created to service its queues. You don't create the threads, you don't own the threads. It's not clear what you mean when you say you suspend and resume threads. Depending on what you mean, you may not be entitled to do that to GCD's threads.

Comment: So, i do not know very well about queues of cocoa, just assumed that they are all threads. i need to learn about them. anyways, i was testing locks(runtimeLock) acquired while method swizzling(method_setImplementation) and calling that method(objc_msgSend)(http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-437/runtime/objc-runtime-new.m)

Comment: writer uses rwlock_write() to create a semaphore which waits for reader to signal it. when i suspended all other threads and main thread spins on waiting for the semaphore, there is no way for it to get signalled. but when i pause execution semaphore_wait() returns and execution continues. its somehow signalled!? i thought they are all separate threads but it seems they are not. so what should i use to run each code on its separate threads to test this scenario?

Comment: "queues of cocoa, just assumed that they are all threads." Not at all. They are a very powerful abstraction built on top of threads, but you should not think about the threads themselves. Think about the queues. You definitely should not reach in and modify the threads out from under GCD. You should not be surprised if the program behaves bizarrely in that case. Beyond that, see the excellent links @Rob provides.

Comment: I tried with performSelectorInBackground:withObject: to run it on a detached thread but even in that case, pausing while waiting in semaphore_wait(), it suddenly returns although semaphore is not signalled. so, i suspect whether it is a feature of XCode lldb or a kind of bug...

Comment: semaphore_wait() returns with value 14, KERN_ABORTED which is defined as "The caller was blocked due to a negative count on the semaphore, and was awoken for a reason not related to the semaphore subsystem" here (http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/semaphore_wait.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that lldb has a problem with SIGSTOP message. Check the following lldb revision.

> **Revision 155560**
>
> Suspend program threads before sending the SIGSTOP & resuming, so other threads won't get into trouble while we are waiting for the SIGSTOP.
>
> rdar://problem/11174834
>
> https://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&sortby=log&sortdir=down&revision=155560

The problem arises when debugging a semaphore_wait() that's on the main thread, semaphore_wait() on background threads are immune to this lldb problem.

Also, **dispatch_semaphore_wait()** is immune to this problem because it uses **dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow()** which has the following;

```
case DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER:
    do {
        kr = semaphore_wait(dsema->dsema_port);
    } while (kr == KERN_ABORTED);
```

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libdispatch/libdispatch-84.5.3/src/semaphore.c

So, it resumes on waiting when semaphore_wait() returns with KERN_ABORTED.

Answer (score 2):

If you have questions about how to do asynchronous development in Cocoa, I'd refer you to the following resources:

- [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091)
- [Grand Central Dispatch Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html)
- WWDC 2012 video [Asynchronous Design Patterns with Blocks, GCD, and XPC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=712)

But, in short, we don't use `semaphore_wait` (or other functions in the same category). We definitely don't suspend threads or anything like that.

When we absolutely need semaphores to communicate between various background threads, we use `dispatch_semaphore_create`, `dispatch_semaphore_wait`, and `dispatch_semaphore_signal` (and I've never seen those exhibit the behavior you describe). For example, I'll create a semaphore, wait for it on a background thread, and signal it 60 seconds later, and this is unaffected by quickly pausing and resuming execution in the debugger:

```
// create a semaphore

dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

// wait for signal on background thread (but don't block main thread)

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSLog(@"Waiting ...");

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    NSLog(@"Waiting done.");
});

// after one minute signal the semaphore

double delayInSeconds = 60.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    NSLog(@"About to signal");

    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);

    NSLog(@"Signal sent");
});
```

This is a fairly impractical example, and a poor use of a semaphore, but it illustrates how you can use one.

But one should never perform any blocking operation on the main thread, much less try to suspend it. In fact, in iOS, if you block the main thread while the app is starting up for too long, the watchdog may kill your app.

And as you'll see when you go through the standard [Cocoa asynchronous design patterns](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=712) video and the [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091), you'll see that standard usage of dispatch queues and operation queues often obviates the need for semaphores altogether (though we occasionally use them).

So, if your question is really about `semaphore_wait`, perhaps someone else can help you. But if you have a question about the appropriate Cocoa asynchronous pattern, let us know what you're functionally trying to accomplish and we can point you in the right direction.

There are several technologies (dispatch queues, operation queues, threads, etc.) available to Cocoa developers, and each has its own merits that makes it well suited for one scenario or another. But we rarely need to resort to direct thread programming anymore and just don't find ourselves using `semaphore_wait` or attempting to suspend threads.